# CSS - Combine text shadow with a text outline?

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I'm trying to accomplish this (don't mind the red background)[image]

So here is what I got I can get a border around the text but then I can't combine it with a text shadow... How can I get around this? Maybe it's something with `:before :after` statements?

```css
h1, h2 { 
    font-family: Chicago;
    font-size: 38px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    letter-spacing: 1.73px;
    
    
    

    /*
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000; 
    
    THIS WILL GIVE THE TEXT THE SHADOW*/
    
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    /*THIS WILL GIVE THE TEXT THE BORDER*/
    
    /*How can I combine these two?*/
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS ZEN GARDEN</h1>
<h1>THE BEAUTY OF CSS DESIGN</h1>
```

Comment: Maybe this is a correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287164/css3-text-effect-text-outline-and-shadow-effect

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kyxrb4bk/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this solution is what you are looking for:

```css
h1 {
   -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
   color: white;
   text-shadow:
     3px 3px 5px #000,
     -1px -1px 5px #000,  
     1px -1px 5px #000,
     -1px 1px 5px #000,
      1px 1px 5px #000;
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS ZEN GARDEN</h1>
<h1>THE BEAUTY OF CSS DESIGN</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

have a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bayleymauger/m2supe1h/1/) fiddle.
you have to use -webkit-text-stroke and then you can use the stroke and shadow separately

```css
h1, h2 { 
    font-family: Chicago;
    font-size: 38px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    letter-spacing: 1.73px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    }
```

```html
<h1>CSS ZEN GARDEN</h1>
<h1>THE BEAUTY OF CSS DESIGN</h1>
```

.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but just adding another value with `X` and `Y` set to `-2px` should do it.

```css
h1, h2 { 
    font-family: Chicago;
    font-size: 38px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    letter-spacing: 1.73px;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black, -2px -2px 10px black;
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS ZEN GARDEN</h1>
<h1>THE BEAUTY OF CSS DESIGN</h1>
```

Note that in the above snippet, I've added `-2px -2px 10px black` which is `-2px` is `X`, the other is `Y` and the last which is `10px` is the shadow spread.

Answer (score 2):

Something close to what your looking for.

```css
h1, h2 { 
    font-family: Chicago;
    font-size: 38px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    letter-spacing: 1.73px;
    
    
    

    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 5px black, 0 0 5px black;
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS ZEN GARDEN</h1>
<h1>THE BEAUTY OF CSS DESIGN</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one for all browsers worth covering:

```css
h1, h2 { 
    font-family: Chicago;
    font-size: 38px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    letter-spacing: 1.73px;
    
    
    text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #000, -2px 0 0 #000, 0 2px 0 #000, 0 -2px 0 #000, 1px 1px #000, -1px -1px 0 #fff, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000; /* Firefox 3.5+, Opera 9+, Safari 1+, Chrome, IE10 */

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(Color=#000000,Strength=1); /* IE<10 */

}
```

```html
<h1>CSS ZEN GARDEN</h1>
<h1>THE BEAUTY OF CSS DESIGN</h1>
```

Or

```css
h1, h2 { 
    font-family: Chicago;
    font-size: 38px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    letter-spacing: 1.73px;
    
    

    
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #000;


}
```

```html
<h1>CSS ZEN GARDEN</h1>
<h1>THE BEAUTY OF CSS DESIGN</h1>
```